# Order by effect only on results through 10 of 100 with ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, pagination

In my app, I order by field `creationTime`  my array of orders, and its effect only on results through **10** (or the selected option) of length of my orders array.

I need to effect that on all the array of my orders items.

So when I choose the **option 5**, I will see only five orders, in order-by field `creationTime` from all the orders, not only from those **5** orders.

**ng-repeat:**

```
<select style="width: auto;  display: inline;" class="form-control col-xs-2" data-ng-model="viewby" data-ng-change="setItemsPerPage(viewby)">
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>50</option>
</select>

<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4  animation animated category" id="bpBox" data-ng-repeat="app in orders.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage )) | orderBy:'creationTime':true | filter:searchItems">

    <div class="pagination" id="pagination">
        <pagination total-items="totalItems" data-ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
    </div>
```

And my **app.js** file:

```
$scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    console.log("length of totalItems : " + $rootScope.totalItems)
};

$scope.pageChanged = function() {
    console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
    console.log("length of totalItems : " + $rootScope.totalItems)

};

$scope.setItemsPerPage = function(num) {
    $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
    $scope.currentPage = 1; //reset to first page
}
```

How can I order by field `creationTime` the all array of orders, and show the selected number of items, in the selected number of pages in angularjS?

Answer (score 1):

You simply have your filter in the wrong order; you're clipping the entire list before it is filtered. When the | symbol (pipe) is used, the output of the previous statement/operation is fed into the next like so:

```
limitTo : 10 | orderBy:'creationTime':true | filter:searchItems
```

In this case the list is limited to 10 elements, these 10 elements are then sorted by creation time, and then the elements are filtered by the search value.

You can make use of the limitTo filter at the end to create an effect of pages. I have not tested but the code below should work:

```
data-ng-repeat="app in orders | orderBy:'creationTime':true | filter:searchItems | limitTo : itemsPerPage : (currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage)"
```

The limitTo filter works in the following way.

```
limitTo : limit : start
```

Comment: Thank you @ModerateSkill, Its Worked!

Comment: If you could upvote and set as the accepted answer @AsrasLior that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @ModerateSkill  now while its filtered like we want, i can see that the `pagination` is now not work and when i delete the limit to, the `pagination` work and move pages. How can it be fixed ?  i tried to see this but no success .  * [http://embed.plnkr.co/eheFSh/] *